"flutterfire configure" command won't let me type in a package name
Pretty self-explanatory. I've installed all of the flutter and firebase command line tools, went to do a flutterfire configure command, but when it reaches the step where it asks "Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration," it won't let me type in a package name! And then I inevitably get hit with the following:

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android project_name (android) --package-name= --json --project=project
ERROR: Package name for Android app cannot be empty

I have no idea how to fix this.

I've had this in the past too, and it seemed to be something with how line wraps/breaks in the input are handled. I worked around it by entering the Android package name on the command line with:
--android-package-name=<ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME>


For me, getting firebase working in my flutter/vsCode app was a nightmare, every step was a problem. After activating flutterfire_cli, I kept getting flutterfire being an unrecognized keyword whenever I tried flutterfire configure command. The problem was, I had not set the ENV variable to the flutterfire.bat file. Once it's done had to restart vsCode. But even then flutterfire configure would not let me enter the full package name to complete the process. After many attempts I figured the command to get it working was flutterfire configure -a"com.xxxxxx.xxxx"
In short,

npm install -g firebase-tools
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
firebase login
flutterfire configure -a"com.xxxx.xxxxxx"


Adding -a"..." worked for me, many thanks! Getting firebase running with flutter is such a ballache!!

Another alternative solution is to open a new terminal.

I did this in vscode and it worked for the second terminal.


Copy the application ID.
Place the cursor at the place you want to write, and right-click on the mouse.
It will automatically paste the application ID.


On windows 11, I used windows powershell (admin) - that way I could type the android package name

I had the same issue when using the terminal in Android Studio. I switched to the macOS terminal, and it allowed me to input the package name without any problems. It’s strange, but it worked for me

i was trying in android studio and getting issue while typing full package name. then i move to project directory and open cmd from here and then i tried flutterfire configure --my project name then from cmd im able to type full package name. this is spacing / line break  issue.

If you open a terminal on a Mac, navigate to the project, and run the command flutterfire configure , it should work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
